# parse multipart/form-data response in spring

Tags: java, spring

I need to receive multipart/form-data response
but i have no idea on how to parse this kind of response

For example

```
--mf8sckatxs4PpMnOLF6ltSv26ZJc5qxy9qq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="arguments"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 311
[{"code":200,"message":"123"}]

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_0"; filename="0_BODY_feature"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 407 
binarydata
```

Comment: Can you please provide complete request? curl maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Spring you already have the Apache fileupload and http classes available. `MultipartStream` is designed to be attached to an incoming byte stream and can provide progress updates as data arrives.

This simple example illustrates a non-streaming scenario where you've already buffered the whole incoming body.

```
byte[] yourResponse = ... // the whole response as a byte array
String yourContentType = ... // the Content-Type header string

ContentType contentType = ContentType.parse(yourContentType);

MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(
  new ByteArrayInputStream(yourResponse),
  contentType.getParameter("boundary").getBytes(), 
  1024,    // internal buffer size (you choose)
  null);   // progress indicator (none)

boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();
while (nextPart) {

  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  String partHeaders = multipartStream.readHeaders();
  multipartStream.readBodyData(output);

  // do something with the multi-line part headers
  // do something with the part 'output' byte array

  nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
}
```

Add exception handling as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can store and separate those values in an Array of Strings:

```
String[] array = "allyourinputtext".split(";");
```

This will separate the values after a semicolon. Then, you can access each value by doing this:

```
String content = array[0];
String name = array[1];
...
```

This doesn't solve the WHOLE problem(since not all values are separated by semicolons), but you can play with the arguments you pass to split() to separate your values.

Note: If you want to parse a String to int (the length value for example) you can use:

```
int length = Integer.parseInt(array[index];
```

Comment: but i think it's not easy to parse complex mulitpart

Answer (score 0):

My situation: I knew the multipart that I'm receiving is a multivaluemap like this:

> MultiValueMap<String, Resource>

First of all, you need to figure out the boundary.

```
    String contentTypeHeader = response.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
    String boundary = null;

    if (contentTypeHeader != null) {
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType(contentTypeHeader);
        boundary = mediaType.getParameter("boundary");
    }
```

Then, make the multipart stream.

```
MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(body),
            boundary.getBytes(),
            1024,
            null);
```

Make a multivaluemap from this multiPartStream

```
boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();
    while (nextPart) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Read the headers of the current part.
        // After .readHeaders(), the stream's position will be at the start of the part's body, ready for you to read the part's actual content.
        multipartStream.readHeaders();
        multipartStream.readBodyData(output);

        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(output.toByteArray());
        multiValueMap.add("file", resource);
        nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
    }
    return multiValueMap;
```